# How to set the default of a Date Filter to a calculated value?

Tags: filter, date-time

I have a List web part that has a (hidden) date column.  I've added a Date Filter web part and connected it to the list. The filter is working.

Setting the default to a calculated value doesn't seem to be an option in the edit menu.

How can I set the default value for a Filter to be a calculated value? For example, I have a formula to calculate the next upcoming Wednesday: `=TODAY()+MOD(11-WEEKDAY(TODAY()),7)`

But where do I put this formula? I want this to be the default value for the Date Filter.

I'm a SharePoint Noob so I apologize for not knowing the proper terms.  I'ave added a picture to hopefully make it clearer:

[image]

Comment: can you explain bit more, so all can get clear picture

Comment: I added a picture and hopefully better explanation

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, Scenario is you have a date filter for which you need next Wednesday's date as default, which will fetch data from Event List.

Comment: Yes, Exactly....

Comment: use jquery to set the date value for this control?

Comment: How/Where do I add JQuery in SharePoint? I don't see anywhere to do this.

Comment: in the same page add a content editor webpart, and add the script there

Comment: Ok, so I got that, I can change the Date Filter using JQuery.  Do you know how to call it to action the filter based on the new values (provided by the JQuery script?)